24.04 lts server appears to loop during install into a vm. after configuring apt
Install lts 24.04 server into a VM
During installing system in the subiquity/... step after configuring apt
curtin cmd in-target - stops turning
After >30 min there is no response.
Host system shows 25% CPU use.
Disk reads but with almost no disk writes.
It appears to be looping. What is it doing?
log shows:
get:28 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f metadata [116 B]
ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
retry 2 more
err:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
connection failed [ip: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]

Is this a too busy connection failure?
How to we know what error response was?
InRelease file appears to be there.
I can view it online.
Does it need a .gpg file also?
given that this is accessing security should it be using https?

what works for me is just disable the internet (WIFI) during the setup phase and everything is fine so seems like there is a possible timeout or recurring issue in these repose for some regions, may be disabling the internet will help to complete setup

Thanks, obvious in hindsight, the installer MUST be able to handle NO internet access. Now gets past that step.
